# Rolling standard deviation using parts of data in dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to be able to calculate rolling standard deviation based on part of the data in the dataframe. An example will explain what I want to accomplish.

```
                   A         B         C
2000-01-01  0.425615  1.679789 -1.903056
2000-01-02  0.791313  0.562471  0.098124
2000-01-03  1.223165 -0.548387 -1.558204
2000-01-04  0.354931 -0.685773  0.647817
2000-01-05  1.137434  1.000594  0.428180
2000-01-06 -0.265311 -1.807045  0.533477
2000-01-07  0.717505  1.647540 -0.141123
2000-01-08 -2.405664  1.278410  1.043872
2000-01-09  0.463943  0.982042 -0.382241
2000-01-10 -0.403267 -0.615421  0.583384
2000-01-11 -0.714163  0.470505 -0.291396
2000-01-12  0.209979 -0.118331 -0.369776
2000-01-13 -0.779638  0.924612 -0.477497
2000-01-14  0.149868 -0.376292  0.747637
2000-01-15 -0.464360  0.821400  1.412874
```

This is what I would like to be able to do:

1. The calculation should be done rolling for each column.
2. I would like to calculate the rolling standard deviation using data for
   every n:th date
       in the dataftame. If n=3 and I want to calculate the standard
       deviation for 2000-01-15 using the values for the
       following dates: 2000-01-15, 2000-01-12, 2000-01-09, 2000-01-06,
       2000-01-03. For 2000-01-14 I use 2000-01-14, 2000-01-11, 2000-01-08,
       2000-01-05, 2000-01-02. The same logic for the other dates to get a rolling standard deviation.
3. It would be great if the logic could be applied for other
   calculations. What I can't figure out is how to switch between
   different resolutions of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window_step_size = 3
rolling_window = 3
>>> pd.rolling_std(df.ix[df.index[::-1][::window_step_size][::-1]], window=rolling_window)
                   A         B         C
2000-01-03       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-06       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-09  0.744288  1.396749  1.048535
2000-01-12  0.370182  1.404848  0.525129
2000-01-15  0.479753  0.594379  1.032831
```

`df.index[::-1]` reverses the dates in the index so that the most recent date is first.  `df.ix[df.index[::-1][::window_step_size]` then takes every `nth` value from this index (e.g. every third date).  Finally, df.index[::-1][::window_step_size][::-1] resorts the index with the oldest date first.

```
>>> df.index[::-1][::window_step_size][::-1]
Index([u'2000-01-03', u'2000-01-06', u'2000-01-09', u'2000-01-12', u'2000-01-15'], dtype='object')
```

Based on this new index, select the values from the database:

```
>>> df.ix[df.index[::-1][::window_step_size][::-1]]

                   A         B         C
2000-01-03  1.223165 -0.548387 -1.558204
2000-01-06 -0.265311 -1.807045  0.533477
2000-01-09  0.463943  0.982042 -0.382241
2000-01-12  0.209979 -0.118331 -0.369776
2000-01-15 -0.464360  0.821400  1.412874
```

You can now use the regular `pd.rolling_std` function for your chosen rolling window.

```
pd.rolling_std(df.ix[df.index[::-1][::window_step_size][::-1]], window=rolling_window)
```

**EDIT** To get daily values, you can concatenate.

```
def roll_sd(df, rolling_window, window_step_size):
    return pd.rolling_std(df.ix[df.index[::-1][::window_step_size][::-1]], 
                          window=rolling_window)

df_sd = pd.concat([roll_sd(df.iloc[0:len(df)-n], rolling_window, window_step_size) 
                   for n in range(window_step_size)])

df_sd.sort_index()
                   A         B         C
2000-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-02       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-03       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-04       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-05       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-06       NaN       NaN       NaN
2000-01-07  0.192205  1.356544  1.305998
2000-01-08  1.953373  0.360948  0.480009
2000-01-09  0.744288  1.396749  1.048535
2000-01-10  0.571905  1.327296  0.438081
2000-01-11  1.772152  0.410464  0.668307
2000-01-12  0.370182  1.404848  0.525129
2000-01-13  0.778805  1.155806  0.542145
2000-01-14  1.299902  0.827427  0.701223
2000-01-15  0.479753  0.594379  1.032831
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need one rolling value for each date, not every third date.

Comment: Fantastic! I need some time to try to understand what is happening in the code but it looks very promising. Thanks!

Comment: I can't say that I understand this completely yet but I would like to have a value for 2000-01-15 as well. It should be based on the standard dev. for  2000-01-15, 2000-01-12, 2000-01-09, 2000-01-06, 2000-01-03.

Comment: It works but I have problems understand what for n in range(4) means in in this context. Why 4? I'm new to Pandas and it is powerful but not always easy  to understand.

Comment: Should be the window step size. I've amended.  `>>> [n for n in range(3)]` results in `[0, 1, 2]`